# Function for filling in values to adjacent cells

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a Google sheet (Form Connector) that uses a form for users to input data into. From there, another sheet (Summary) gives a summary of all the data that is put into it via the form. Another sheet gives a breakdown of all the data (Daily RT). The Daily RT sheet is shown below

[image: Daily RT sheet]

Within the cells that say "No RT" is the following formula, with respect to their row.

```
=IFNA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER('Form Connector'!$D$2:$F,'Form Connector'!$C$2:$C=$B$1,'Form Connector'!$B$2:$B=$A3),1,20),IF($A3<TODAY(),"No RT",""))
```

Column A is the dates, B:D is data as well as E:G. I've been focusing on the IF($A3<TODAY(),"No RT","") in the formula to be able to replace the "No RT" part of it.

**Question:**
Is there any way, instead of "No RT", to fill in 0's in columns B:D using the one formula which is in column B via an array?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VxYyLMmqpNcX66okNbcH8LHqcu2gj1ONBc7ao8FNkIU/edit?usp=sharing)

The desired result is to have columns B:D filled in with 0's instead of "No RT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in B3 after you remove everything from B3:D range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP($A3:$A, 
 FILTER('Form Connector'!$B2:$F, 'Form Connector'!$C2:$C=B$1), 
 {3,4,5}, 0))*1)
```

[image]

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A3:$A>=TODAY(),,IFNA(VLOOKUP($A3:$A, 
 FILTER('Form Connector'!$B2:$F, 'Form Connector'!$C2:$C=B$1), 
 {3,4,5}, 0))*1))
```

Comment: This works perfectly! only issue I have now is that the formula I had before took into account that the cells after today's date would be blank, so each day that passes, the formula automatically "fills" in the sheet. how would I incorporate that logic into this formula?

Comment: @Richard answer updated

Comment: That works! Thank you!